# Extracting/deleting rows from time series without using index information

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, drop

I have a simple problem. I want to get a subset of time series with a certain condition that is not dependent on time index. I have a very huge dataset, I am just giving a small example to make my problem understandable.

|  | row_num | marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 | 1 | 99 |
| 2016-01-02 | 2 | 98 |
| 2016-01-01 | 3 | 95 |
| 2016-01-01 | 4 | 90 |
| 2016-01-02 | 5 | 40 |
| 2016-01-03 | 6 | 80 |
| 2016-01-04 | 7 | 20 |

**but my problem is when I try to drop, it always drops by index and delete all index of 2016-01-01 and 2016-01-02.
I can not manually extract such a subset because data size is very huge and there are so many duplicate indices**. How to solve this problem?

Comment: What does your drop statement look like? `df[~df['row_num'].isin([1,5])]` will work in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @ScottBoston. It worked. I was trying this statement and it was deleting all the duplicate indices as well. df.drop(df.loc[df.row_num==1].index,inplace=True). Ur suggested statement worked for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
df[~df['row_num'].isin([1,5])]
```

Output:

```
              row_num  marks
  2016-01-02        2     98
  2016-01-01        3     95
  2016-01-01        4     90
  2016-01-03        6     80
  2016-01-04        7     20
```